# Add another ip on the same network card in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, network-programming, ipv6, ipv4

i know that there isn't code inside my question, but i think this is an interesting question... 
Is possible to add a new `ip` ( preferably `ipv6` ) on the wifi network card still connected over `ipv4`? I have to talk at the same time with a router (`ipv4`) and another device (`ipv6`). So is possible to develop this over `objective-c`? so on the `iphone`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iPhone?  Not a chance (AFAIK).  I could see that introducing all sorts of security vulnerabilities that would seriously impair the entire purpose of sandboxed apps. *

That said, the iPhone is perfectly capable of binding both an IPv4 and IPv6 address, and will do so automatically in various cases (such as when an IPv6 capable router is offering up both, as mine do).  You should watch the Advanced Networking (or something to that effect) videos from WWDC 2010 and 2011.  But this is handled at the device, not app, level.

On OS X you have the [System Configuration framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_Intro/SC_Intro.html) in the Core OS layer of the system stack.  I *think* you can use it to set IPs, but I've never really looked into it, and the iOS System Configuration APIs appear to be a small subset of the OS X APIs.

*: There may be some [exceptions](http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2010/09/ios-4-1-undocumented-vpn-api-used-by-cisco-anyconnect/) for managing VPNs, but this appears to be private API most likely granted special dispensation by Apple.